# Change label text acc. to python variable

Tags: python, properties, kivy

I am writing code for a heating control system.

I just want to be able to change the label texts FROM WITHIN PYTHON.
By that I mean, NOT in the GUI code, but somewhere else in the main.

Here is my MWE:

```
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import multiprocessing 
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class Data (Widget):
    top = StringProperty('hiii')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)


global mydata     
mydata=Data()

class myw (BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myw, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        VERT = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        o = Label(text='Oben: ',
                  font_size=120)
        m = Label(text='Mitte: ',
              font_size=120)
        u = Label(text='Unten: ',
              font_size=120)
        a = Label(text='Aussen: ',
              font_size=120)

        mydata.bind(top=o.setter('text'))

       VERT.add_widget(o)
       VERT.add_widget(m)
       VERT.add_widget(u)
       VERT.add_widget(a)

       onoff = Button(text='Ein',
              font_size=120,
              size_hint=(0.3, 1))
       self.add_widget(VERT)
       self.add_widget(onoff)



class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return myw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        global myapp
        myapp=TutorialApp()
        app_runner=multiprocessing.Process(target=myapp.run)
        app_runner.start()
        time.sleep(3)
        mydata.top='new value assigned'
        print (mydata.top)
        time.sleep(5)
        app_runner.terminate()
    except Exception as e:
        print ('error occured', e)
```

I deliberately declared the variable 'mydata' outside the kivy code, such that i can access it from elsewhere in the code (not shown here).

Comment: I know! But that didn't work for me ...

Comment: it works perfectly fine. The only thing I see for now is `string='now changed'`, which is different variable than `RootWidget.string`. to get that variable use `my_app.root.string = 'something'`. It should change. However, your code gives me just a `RuntimeError` and something about `freeze_support` so...

Comment: yes, I get an error with that approach as well... I edited the original code with a second attempt...

Comment: I meant, the binding works fine. If done right you can check with inspector module when you change a bound variable. MP is nice tool, but I think it won't go this way. Changing a variable this way seems weird to me. MP won't allow you to get an object or a value through unless you make something global and ___lock___ it. With a lock in _endless_ loop (App.run()) there would be no chance to change it. If your attempt is to make two _separate_ apps use OSC. If two _windows_, check [Philip's article](https://medium.com/@PhilipAndrews/the-kivy-frontier-multiple-independent-windows-a23717c64547).

Comment: I only want one app running in another process. From the main I want to change labels, as simulated above with `mydata.top='new value assigned'`. 
I don't know what do make global. I made the data and the date instance global in the code above, but the change in mydata still does not propagate into the running app. (see edited code above)

Comment: KeyWeeUser wrote : 'Changing a variable this way seems weird to me.'
I don't know how to do it. 
I would like to point out that what I am trying to do is VERY EASY. Just update a label from the main, in whatever way.

Comment: It seems weird to me because you want to make another process and change it this way. I presume that you want to set/get the temperature to/from some other device, let's say raspberry. _Why_ do you want to do it with multiple processes? I mean, you can use [`Thread`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application) directly, so that it doesn't freeze GUI, but that's not communication. And for communication between multiple devices you should use [OSC](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lib.osc.html). I'm not sure how to do it. I only see app-osc-app.

Answer (score 1):

Using threading instead of multiprocessing solved the problem.

So instead of

```
app_runner=multiprocessing.Process(target=myapp.run)
```

it now reads:

```
app_runner=threading.Thread(target=myapp.run)
```